# i want to transform it to another XML using XSL file. but i am not able to delete <TnAddress> field i want its all child

Tags: xslt

Input XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<EsrOrder>
    <Header>
        <OrderId>
                865975
        </OrderId>
        <Metadata>
                None
        </Metadata>
    </Header>

    <ESRBody>
        <TN>
            6543219785
        </TN>
        <Tntype>
            Wireline
        </Tntype>
        <Priority>
            High
        </Priority>
        <TnOwnerName>
            Ching Chang
        </TnOwnerName>
        <TnAddress>
            <BasicAddress>
                101,Clssic View 44 Baikunth Dham Colony
            </BasicAddress>
            <Landmark>
                Near Anand Bazar
            </Landmark>
            <City>
                Indore
            </City>
            <State>
                Madhya Pradesh
            </State>
            <Country>
                India
            </Country>
        </TnAddress>
    </ESRBody>
</EsrOrder>
```

XSLT USED -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">



 <!--  Identity transform -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy>
  <Sea_Element>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Sea_Element>
 </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EsrOrder/Header">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EsrOrder/ESRBody">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />    
</xsl:template>

<!--<xsl:template match="EsrOrder/ESRBody/TnAddress">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />    
</xsl:template>-->

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

output which i get -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sea_Element>

        <OrderId>
                865975
        </OrderId>
        <Metadata>
                None
        </Metadata>



        <TN>
            6543219785
        </TN>
        <Tntype>
            Wireline
        </Tntype>
        <Priority>
            High
        </Priority>
        <TnOwnerName>
            Ching Chang
        </TnOwnerName>
        <TnAddress>
            <BasicAddress>
                101,Clssic View 44 Baikunth Dham Colony
            </BasicAddress>
            <Landmark>
                Near Anand Bazar
            </Landmark>
            <City>
                Indore
            </City>
            <State>
                Madhya Pradesh
            </State>
            <Country>
                India
            </Country>
        </TnAddress>

</Sea_Element>
```

Where as Output required -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sea_Element>

        <OrderId>
                865975
        </OrderId>
        <Metadata>
                None
        </Metadata>



        <TN>
            6543219785
        </TN>
        <Tntype>
            Wireline
        </Tntype>
        <Priority>
            High
        </Priority>
        <TnOwnerName>
            Ching Chang
        </TnOwnerName>

            <BasicAddress>
                101,Clssic View 44 Baikunth Dham Colony
            </BasicAddress>
            <Landmark>
                Near Anand Bazar
            </Landmark>
            <City>
                Indore
            </City>
            <State>
                Madhya Pradesh
            </State>
            <Country>
                India
            </Country>


</Sea_Element>
```

its just one Parent field  which is not getting eliminated.
Even if the same code is working for other tags for removal
could i get the reason and correct XSL....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the use of `copy-of` prevent the application of any template matching the inner elements like `TnAddress`.

Try this simpler XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!--  Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Elements that should be dropped - copying only their content -->
  <xsl:template match="EsrOrder|Header|ESRBody|TnAddress">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Set the root element -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Sea_Element>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Sea_Element>
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```